# Regex replace just a portion of string

Tags: regex

I have this code:

```
var regex = /ancesterComboValue=.*(&|$)/;
if( regex.test(this.proxy.url)) {
   this.proxy.url = this.proxy.url.replace(regex,'ancesterComboValue='+newValue);
}
else {
   this.proxy.url += '&ancesterComboValue='+newValue;
}
```

Which replaces `ancesterComboValue` parameter in a URL.

But it doesn't replace the `&` character, is it special?

Also, can I just replace something in the pattern of the regex? For example, in a URL string there are many `=` symbols, if I just want to replace this one: `ancesterComboValue=` with a `%`, how can I do it without specifying the whole phrase (`ancesterComboValue%`)?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Jorge, can you clarify your question a little bit? Provide an example of a url you're matching and what your expected results are?

Answer (score 0):

In case it can still help you, answering this ancient question as no one has done so yet.

Your search regex should look like this:

```
ancesterComboValue=[^&#\s]*
```

This ensures that:

- we don't run over the next `&`
- we don't run over multiple lines
- if there is a tag anchor as in `#top`, we don't replace it by mistake.

You can see the matches on [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/lM1yV1).

**Explain Regex**

```
ancesterComboValue=      # 'ancesterComboValue='
[^&#\s]*                 # any character except: '&', '#', whitespace
                         # (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
```